# How to delete all unprotected rows in a range of particular sheets from Google Sheets using Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have several protected range in a sheet of my Google Sheets for example, A2 to F40 and then A45 to F90. I do this protected range using a button (menu--submenu). But there are few rows of data unprotected throughout a range of particular sheets having names using alphabets and numbers together (e.g. ICT4113, MATH4104 or HUM4119). There are few other sheets having names containing only alphabets which does not require this function.

How can I delete those unprotected rows of data throughout a range of specific sheets inside function onOpen() without any trigger. Just when I want to delete, I will press a sub-menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to completely delete the rows which has no protected ranges for the specific sheets using Google Apps Script.

  - There are several specific sheets you want to achieve this.
- You want to run the script by the custom menu on Google Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer? The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve data range.
2. Create an object from the protected range. This is used for removing from the cleared rows.
3. Create range list for clearing rows using the object.
4. Delete the rows without the rows of the protected ranges.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and set the sheet name, and reopen the Spreadsheet. By this, the custom menu is set. When you run `myFunction`, the cells of rows without the protected range are deleted.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu').addItem('run script', 'myFunction').addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().filter(s => /\d/.test(s.getSheetName())).forEach(sheet => {
    // 1. Retrieve data range.
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();

    // 2. Create an object from the protected range. This is used for removing from the cleared rows.
    const protectedRanges = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).map(e => {
      const r = e.getRange();
      const start = r.getRow();
      return {start: start, end: r.getNumRows() + start - 1};
    });

    // 3. Create range list for clearing rows using the object.
    let rangeList = [];
    for (let r = 2; r <= dataRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
      let bk = false;
      for (let e = 0; e < protectedRanges.length; e++) {
        if (protectedRanges[e].start == r) {
          r = protectedRanges[e].end;
          bk = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!bk) rangeList.push(`A${r}:${r}`);
    }

    // 4. Delete the rows without the rows of the protected ranges.
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges().reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [Custom Menus in G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [getProtections(type)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getprotectionstype)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: Please note that I need to delete all the unprotected rows of data. Not clearing only. And I need to do this deleting rows of data for a range of specific sheets of a spreadsheet. For instance those sheets having alphanumeric names like ICTE4113, MATH4115, HUM4118, etc. I have few other tabs there like Master (only alphabetical name) which does not require this function.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. You want to completely delete the rows without the protected ranges for several specific sheets. I understood like this from your replying. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: You are right. Could you please take the sheet names automatically. In my spreadsheet there are 8 subjects/sheets/tabs which codes are like ICTE4113, MATH4110, HUM4103, etc (no blank space, only alphabets and number) and there are other tabs also like Master, TempDataSet (only alphabets, no number is there). First we need to collect all the sheet names having both alphabets and numbers together and do the function of removing unprotected ranges of data to all of them by just pressing a submenu like REFRESH. That's all.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer for your replying. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It is not working correctly. I changed it for a single sheet. The sheet has A2:F84 protected range, then again A85:F90 protected. Then I added few attendance. When I am executing your code it is deleting A85:F90 all rows of data and the header rows as well. So at the end, it is remaining as A1:F83 protected. Please note that the code does not do anything on A1 to F1 (first row as it is header row). And there many protected ranges in the sheet such as A2: F84, A85:F90, A95:F100. Your code should not do anything on all the protected ranges and header rows, all other rows should be deleted.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In this case, when a sheet has the data range and protected ranges are "A1:F100" and "A2: F84, A85:F90, A95:F100", respectively, the rows 91 to 94 are deleted and 1st row is not deleted even when the 1st row is not protected.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you. Please check my other question of switching user roles. I found a simple logic for that.

Comment: One issue is still there. If there is not unprotected rows of data, then it shows error. I think it is better to show a message instead like 'No Unprotected Rows of Data Found!'. Please solve it for me

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. In my environment, when the script is used for the sheet without the protected ranges, no error occurs. So I cannot replicate your situation. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you post it as new question by including the detail information for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. When you can cooprerate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Please note that error occurs if there is NO rows of Unprotected Data. Then the code does not find any range to delete and shows error. It requires a message to show to the user like 'No Unprotected Rows of Data Found!'

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. For example, how about modifying the last line of my script to `if (rangeList.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges().reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));`?

Comment: Thanks it is done now. Please check my another question regarding switching from Editor to Viewer and vice-versa. It is now easier to code for it, I think

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Please check my another question`, if you say about https://stackoverflow.com/q/62241421/7108653 , an answer has already been posted. I think that the answerer is thinking the solution now. So I think that the answerer will resolve your issue. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.