# How to automatically switch from view mode to edit mode and vice-versa

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have several sheets as subjects in my Google Spreadsheet where attendance are recorded from an android app. When I select View mode to Edit mode, attendance can be recorded.

By default I want to keep it in view mode so that students can NOT submit attendance outside the time given by me as a owner of the sheets or the class teachers (editors).

Please note that my sheet users are:

- me as a owner and also editor
- course teachers as a editors (several sheets means several subjects are there)
- the students

All (owner, editors and students) are using university domain specific mail for accessing sheets.

It is also a tedious job for a teacher to enable Edit mode during a class for attendance and then after completing it, again go back to view mode everyday. What I want is to, create a submenu using `onOpen()` function to automate the whole process so that teachers can do it easily.

The Codes are as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Attendance Task')
    .addItem('Refresh Sheet', 'refreshSheet')
    .addToUi();
}

//Refresh Sheet for setting Editor mode to students and taking their attendance from mobile app
function refreshSheet() { 

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //StudentList is a student information sheet where in Column F all the emails of students kept.  
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('StudentList');

  //Need to bring all students emails from Column F of StudentList sheet to students array.  
  var students = [];

  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){
    //Checking the students are in Editor or Viewer Mode
    if(students[0] || students[1] || students[2] in Viewer Mode){
     ss.addEditor(students[i]); 
    }  
  }

  //Now start a timer and after 10 or 20 minutes all students should be removed automatically from Editor to Viewer Mode.    
     ss.removeEditor(students[i]);

}
```

Comment: What are "View mode" and "Edit mode" in your question? Can I ask you about them?

Comment: When sharing a spreadsheet to others, you can set Edit mode or View mode access to them.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In this case, the permission is "Viewer" and "Editor" for Anyone with the link? Or the permission is given with each emails?

Comment: I would like to add this part of code to my another question of deleting unprotected rows of data together so that after opening a sheet, when I press a sub menu like Refresh, it will do both tasks together - opening edit mode for users and delete unprotected rows of data from All Sheets (wrongly mentioned a single sheet to my another post that you answered few minutes earlier today)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, your replying didn't resolve my question. I apologize for my poor English skill. By the way, in your replying, you mentioned about [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62240765/7108653). In this case, my answer I understood was not matched your question? If it's so, I have to delete it and modify it. How about this? I would like to resolve the questions one by one.

Comment: No problem do it one by one. The spreadsheet has a owner (head of department) and few course teachers as editors and all students of a particular grade. The owner, teachers and students are using university domain specific mail to access sheets. You can make them all Viewer but the owner and teachers should have the permission to change the mode - viewer to Editor and vice versa always. By default it should be viewer always.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your this question, in your situation, the permissions of Spreadsheet are managed by emails. So in this case, the Spreadsheet is not publicly shared. The default situation is a part of emails are viewer and other emails except for the part of emails are editor. And you want to change the permissions for a part of emails, while the permissions for other emails except for the part of emails are required to always have the editor. Is my understanding correct? When you have any questions for your previous question, please put them to the previous one.

Comment: Yes, you are partially right. In the spreadsheet there are 8 sheets (consider sheet as subject and each subject there is a teacher). So all these 8 teachers and me (as a owner/creator) has editor access to the Spreadsheet always. So what the teachers are doing during a class is that, enabling Editor mode for all those having the link from our university domain. After class they are just again changing back to viewer mode to all with the link from our university domain. This process need to be automated..

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, only 8 emails are used for the permissions. You don't want to change the permissions of these users of 8 emails. I understood like this. And, other users except for 8 emails are managed by "university domain specific mail". In this case, the Spreadsheet has the permissions of a lot of emails of 8 emails and other users except for 8 emails. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. As there are 8 tabs (subject/sheet, number of tabs may vary) in the spreadsheet, there are eight teachers who need to enable editor mode during class for taking student attendance and me working as a owner of the sheet. Me, all teachers and students are using university domain specific mails to access the sheet. All the teachers are already given the editor access. What you have to do is, enable Viewer mode to Editor mode for 10-15 minutes when the teacher press a sub menu and then automatically goes back to default viewer mode for other users of that domain with the link.

Comment: I would give the teachers webapps to take roll.

Comment: For switching Viewer to Editor, the logic is simple. I shared the sheet through emails to my teachers and they have the shared copy in their google drive. Keep it as it is so that they can do everything on the sheet. For others of a particular domain with the link, it requires switching from default Viewer mode to Editor mode for 10 minutes by pressing a sub men by the course teacher and then automatically goes back to Viewer mode inside onOpen() function, no trigger required. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why isn't changing the permissions programmatically an option? You can simply `addEditors()`/`addViewers()` to the spreadsheet. Moreover, if the user (aka teacher) has the `editor` role, why do you want to change it to `viewer`? @AktaruzzamanLiton

Comment: Please note that I do not want to change modes for teachers, they have the shared copy of the spreadsheet to their Google drive. They will be there always as editors. But for other users (students, don't have the shared copy of the spreadsheet) with the link from a particular domain, the mode need to be changed to Editor mode from default viewer mode for 10 minutes for taking attendance from an android app. After completing attendance, other users' (students) mode should come back to viewer mode. Teachers will remain always as editors.

Comment: Understood that - what I meant is: why not add the students as viewers directly? In this way you will have all the permissions for the spreadsheet specifically for each member (teacher/student/owner) and there will be no need to change them all the time. @AktaruzzamanLiton

Comment: If students are in the viewer mode in Google Sheets, attendance can not be recorded from Android app. It must be in the Editor mode for the students to record attendance. That is the main problem.

Comment: Please note that in the spreadsheet I have a StudentList sheet where in Column F there are student emails. The code needs to be in the onOpen() with no triggers. When I will press a submenu like 'Refresh', it will add the students as editors and after 10 minutes it will remove the previously added editors (students) only automatically. It should not be at 9 or 10 or 11 am as there are many class attendance in the spreadsheet. We cannot change the hardcode. So the time will start when I will press the submenu and within 10 minutes students need to report attendance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a time-based installable trigger in Apps Script which will change the permissions for the students to **editors** in order for them to record the attendance and afterwards change it back to **viewers**.

Assuming the students email addresses are stored in the `students` array, the snippet below will be able to fulfill your task:

#### Snippet

```
function studentsToEditors() {
  var students = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SS");
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++)
    ss.addEditor(students[i]);
}

function studentsToViewers() {
  var students = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SS");
   for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++)
     ss.removeEditor(students[i])
}

function createTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('studentsToEditors')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(9)
      .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('studentsToViewers')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(9)
      .nearMinute(30)
      .create();
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code is composed of three functions:

- `studentsToEditors` which is used to add each student as an editor to the spreadsheet;
- `studentsToViewers` which is used to remove each student as an editor to the spreadsheet;
- `creteTriggers` which is used to create two time-driven triggers:

  - one which will run at approximately 9 and is attached to the `studentsToEditors` function;
  - one which will run at approximately 9:30 (+/- 15 minutes) and is attached to the `studentsToViewers` function;

In this way, the students will be added as editors in order to record their attendance and afterwards removed.

#### Note

The [`nearMinute(minute)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearMinute(Integer)) method used for the `studentsToViewers` specifies the minute at which the trigger runs **(plus or minus 15 minutes)**.

---

#### Update

**Method 1**

If you own a GSuite account which allows you to execute a script for longer than the [6 minutes/script execution time](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), you can use the below method.

You can simply add `Utilities.sleep(300000);` to your code three times in order to monitor the 15 minutes needed.

```
Utilities.sleep(300000);
Utilities.sleep(300000);
Utilities.sleep(300000);
for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
   ss.removeEditor(students[i]);
}
```

**Method 2**

If the quota does not allow you to use the above method, you can create a function which specifically removes the students editors and afterwards attaches a time based trigger to it.

Assuming that you remove the students in a `removeStudents()` function, you can create a trigger like this:

```
function createTrigger(){
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
      .timeBased()
      .after(900000)
      .create();
}
```

If needed, you can also remove the above trigger, depending on your needs/quotas.

Also, please bear in mind that **you** can configure the time-based trigger to fulfill **your** needs by checking this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) and choosing the most appropriate options for **your use-case**.

#### Reference

- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Class ClockTriggerBuilder Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder);
- [Class Utilities Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds);
- [Quotas Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations);

Comment: Thanks but it won't solve my problem. In the spreadsheet I have a StudentList sheet where in Column F there are student IDs. The code needs to be in the onOpen() with no triggers. When I will press a submenu like 'Refresh', it will add the students as editors and after 10 minutes it will remove the editors (students) automatically. It should not be at 9 or 10 or 11 am as there are many class attendance in the spreadsheet. We cannot change the hardcode. So the time will start when I will press the submenu and within 10 minutes students need to report attendance. Please review your code again.

Comment: I apologize that the solution offered did not solve your issue. In order to be able to provide an accurate approach to your problem, would you mind editing your question by including the **code** you have used, as well with a more accurate description of your task? This would be of great help! Cheers!

Comment: Please check now as I added the code from where you can easily understand what I want to accomplish from this work. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please change the Snippet with a complete code. I am new to Apps Script. The codes in my edited post have many errors. From bringing all emails of students to students array from F column of StudentList sheet and so on up to the end of function so that I can copy and paste it to script editor. Thanks in advance.